# How to check for special characters in UNIX?

Tags: unix, grep

I have a fixed width file with 10-15 columns. The file contains alphanumeric values. How do I check for any special characters (like !,@,#,$,% etc.) in the entire file in UNIX ?

Comment: there is a character class called punct .check for it. `[[:punct:]]`, may be it help.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
grep -vn "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" yourFile
```

or

```
grep -vn "^[[:alnum:]]*$" yourFile
```

> man grep  :
>
> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
>
> -n, --line-number
>                 Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)
>
> [[:alnum:]]  means the character class of numbers and letters in the
>   current locale

Comment: You might want to allow whitespace as valid characters: `grep '[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]'`